# How to cut power to an embedded device without damaging it?

Tags: power-supply, relay, embedded

I have to build a system that shuts-down an embedded device by cutting off the power supply (in case it stops responding).

The device I want to turn off is quite sophisticated (it is a custom PCB which contains multiple processors, FPGAs, microphones etc..)

- It is part of a commercial product (not a hobby project).
- It has to comply with safety standards (precisely the ATEX norm).
- It is handheld and quite small (the size of a laptop more or less).
- The power supply voltage is 12 V and the current consumption is 1 A (average) with peaks of 2 A.

I would like to know what is the 'industrial standard' to do such a thing in a reliable and non-damaging way.

1. **Is it okay to simply put a relay in series with the power supply and cut the power?**
2. **Are there special types of relays that are meant for this task?**
   I read on google about the different types but I am not sure about the pros and cons, my gut feeling tells me that solid state relays could be a good option?

As usual thank you very much for your help!

Comment: if the device is designed for industrial use, then it should already be able to deal with all kinds if power fluctuations, such as without issue

Comment: your question is not answerable without knowing if the device is able to withstand power loss without proper shutdown ... you can always design a UPS that also performs graceful shutdown of the device

Comment: When cutting power to a complicated board, it is best to cut it abruptly, not slowly. So, the question now is: is there a moment better than another, to cut power? I suspect no...

Comment: The device contains 2 SoCs (Systems on Chip), an i.MX6 from NXP and a Zynq Ultrascale+ from Xilinx, as well as an array of microhpnes and an LCD screen. I think the processors/FPGAs are the most sensitive parts

Comment: How is the device originally powered? I.e. does it have a DC plug that user can unplug and replug? If so, how would a relay be any different?

Comment: The device is battery powered, the user shuts it off with a button that triggers a software shutdown (which sometimes fails, hence the need for a hard shutdown). I guess my problem here is that I have never worked on a real product before, and I'd like to make sure that the choices I make are proved and reliable, and not some kind of maker-project hack.

Comment: Should be no issues as long as you break the +12 V and not the GND connection. Only edge case I can think of is a too short power off-power on cycle which can in some cases produce glitches.

Comment: ATEX is a very special case and all manner of concerns exists regarding how to connect power. You might need "zener barriers", fuses and the like. Relays may be problematic to use in an ATEX environment various reasons too: heat, gasses etc. You might want to look into EX approved SSR.

Answer (score 6):

Unless the device requires a UPS it should deal with unexpected power failures. If it’s poorly designed and file system corruption and such like is possible then all bets are off, you may need to request an orderly shutdown (which might not be honored if it’s not responding). The fact it needs power cycling suggest possible serious underlying issues.

As to what kind of relay, a properly specified mechanical type would likely be far more reliable than a solid-state type, but analysis would be required including the consequences of various failure modes.

Comment: Would it be wise to ensure a certain amount of off time?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD  Yes. A well-designed reset strategy in the target system should deal well with any time that's long enough to interrupt the operation (maybe a fraction of  second, some dozens of  mains cycles). If you suspect it's poorly designed then many seconds... as typically recommended on cheap consumer goods such as cable modems.

Answer (score 2):

There is no special concern. You can control the power with any suitable relay or in many cases also with a transistor. The advantages of a relay are that it Just Works - it's easy to use. The advantages of using a transistor are that it's smaller, cheaper and has no moving parts.

Would you be worried about damaging the device by suddenly unplugging it? A relay is just unplugging it with an electromagnet. No real difference.

Comment: I think nothing would happen if the device was unplugged a few times, but maybe there is a safe and reliable way to do this? Also, in the end I imagine the relay will have to be put on the PCB, or somewhere in the device (which is handheld) so maybe the electromechanical relay would be hard to incorporate in the design?

Comment: @leopicchio There is generally no need to make disconnecting the power safer or more reliable. Is there any particular reason you think this device is especially sensitive? Okay, if it's a small handheld thing (and I noticed it is a custom PCB you designed?) you might want to spend the extra time to make a transistor circuit to cut off power instead of a relay.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't think the device is particularly sensitive, but given that it is not a hobby project but an actual commercialized device, I wanted to have the opinion of people with experience in industry on how this thing is usually done :)

Comment: @leopicchio - My warning signals are going off.  Don't accept responsibility for somebody else's poor engineering. Otherwise, they may sue you for how their device behaves after they hired you to design a circuit to protect the device from itself. Advice is buy your friend the best surge protecting power-strip you can afford, and apologize for not being able to fix his device.

Comment: @leopicchio - If you read between the lines on Spehro's answer, he has the same concerns, and the professional answer is "analysis would be required including the consequences of various failure modes" which to me means that you've got to exhaustively test the device (to cover your butt) before you even think about providing a relay to turn it off.  I can hear the lawyers now... "Who caused the data corruption? Is your device responsible? You don't know? Sounds like you didn't do your due diligence..."

Answer (score 2):

The device is battery powered; this means you have relatively low voltage DC power in mind for the shutoff.
A relay is a bad choice here, because your battery power undoubtedly
runs through voltage converters to your targets for reset.
What you want is simply to
apply a short 'off' command to those converters, that
are in turn powering the embedded devices of interest.

The duration of the command should be long enough to
deplete any output filter capacitors, so that your target
devices are definitely powered down.

If the converters are typical switchmode power types,
like [this one (TPS62067)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62067.pdf) it's the 'EN' pin.

This means, however, that you're power-sequencing those
parts (i.e. bypassing the designed-in power sequence),
so some analysis of the whole (not just those embedded parts)
unit is called for.
Trace from the power button, find whatever circuitry
is sequencing the various power startups, and understand how and
why.  You may just want to change the state of the
existing sequence circuitry (which connects to all the
enable pins of the converters) rather than doing a direct OR-gate override.

A relay would be ideal for an AC power interruption, but relay contacts bounce, arc, and have slight resistance, none of which is harmless in a high current/low voltage application.